# Elasticsearch sort terms by pipeline bucket_script aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I index these 2 docs:

```
POST my_index/my_type/1
{
    "name": "Nephi",
    "x": 5
}

POST my_index/my_type/2
{
    "name": "Lehi",
    "x": 10
}
```

Here is my search request:

```
POST my_index/my_type/_search?size=0
{
   "aggs": {
      "some_terms_agg": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "name",
            "order": {
               "the_script_bucket": "asc"
            }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "the_sum": {
               "sum": {
                  "field": "x"
               }
            },
            "the_avg": {
               "avg": {
                  "field": "x"
               }
            },
            "the_script_bucket": {
               "bucket_script": {
                  "buckets_path": {
                     "a": "the_sum.value",
                     "b": "the_avg.value"
                  },
                  "script": "a + b"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I get an error like this:

> Invalid term-aggregator order path [the_script_bucket]. Unknown aggregation [the_script_bucket]

But when I change `the_script_bucket` to another aggregation like `the_sum` or `the_avg` it works fine.  I'm sure this is because `the_script_bucket` is a pipeline aggregation, but I want the terms to be sorted based on `the_script_bucket` so I could (for example) see the top 10 values for 100,000 docs.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is currently an open issue in elasticsearch
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8486
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/ordering-terms-aggregation-based-on-pipeline-metric/31839

Answer (score 2):

Update: it's definitely not possible, for performance concerns.

The issue has been closed for the following reason:

> We only add features to Elasticsearch which are horizontally scalable. Whatever we add should work when you're running one node on your laptop with 50GB of data or 1000 nodes in your data server with 50 PB of data.
>
> Fetching all terms from all shards does not scale horizontally, and so we will not add it.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8486#issuecomment-265496605

You have to do this on the client side: fetch ALL buckets (which means you should know in advance how much items it would return), then sort them yourself. Completely counter-productive, I know. Good luck.